# connecting stripe to react native app error

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying test a payment using stripe for my react native project. But when I press the pay button i get an error stating. since there is not an official doc for stripe for react native, its been challenging

here the error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'StripeBridge.createPayment')

onPaymentPress
    PaymentScreen.js:17:33
```

what that error mean exactly and how do I remove it?
essentially my goal is for the user to make a one time payment once they enter their details and press the pay button

here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View,ImageBackground,NativeModules} from 'react-native'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';


var StripeBridge = NativeModules.StripeBridge;


export default function PaymentScreen({navigation}) {
    const [ccNumber, setCCNumber] = useState('')
    const [month, setMonth] = useState('')
    const [year, setYear] = useState('')
    const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState('')
    const [cvv, setCvv] = useState('')

    const onPaymentPress = () => {
        
        
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/createStripePaymentIntent', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson.setupIntentId);

        StripeBridge.createPayment(
          responseJson.setupIntentId,
          ccNumber,
          month,
          year,
          cvv,
          zipCode,
          (error, res, payment_method) => {
            if (res == 'SUCCESS') {
              Alert.alert('Stripe Payment', 'Your Stripe payment succeeded', [
                {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
              ]);
            }
          },
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    //    setTimeout(navigation.navigate("Products"), 1000) 
    }

    return (
        
                </View>
                ......

                   style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => onPaymentPress()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Submit Payment</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.footerView}>
                <Text style={styles.footerText}> Payment secured by Stripe  <Text  style={styles.footerLink}></Text></Text>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    )
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with ReactNative but going by https://ademcan.net/blog/2020/03/25/use-stripe-3d-secure-confirmation-system-in-react-native-ios/ , that link tells me you have to create a Native iOS module to bridge to the iOS SDK, have you done that?

Comment: I did create a bridge to the ios sdk. I added stripebridge.m and stripebridge.h and did a  pod install